# I'm having much trouble figuring a MySQL error log

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, glassfish

I made a web-app using JSF, MySQL, and NetBeans(web-app template-design).

Here's the error-trace I get: http://adelazzam.com/errorTrace.htm

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:397)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.getServerSession(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:202)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:207)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.getCriteriaBuilder(EntityManagerWrapper.java:883)
    at jpa.session.AbstractFacade.count(AbstractFacade.java:56)
    at jsf.ToolController.getPagingInfo(ToolController.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:302)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:72)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:163)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstEqual.getValue(AstEqual.java:54)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:190)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered(UIComponentBase.java:416)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1607)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:848)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1613)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1616)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.doRenderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:420)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.JspViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(JspViewHandlingStrategy.java:209)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:127)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
Error Code: 0
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:369)
    ... 56 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.DataSource.getConnection(DataSource.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:126)
    ... 61 more
```

What is the cause and how can I fix it?

Comment: My hunch is that my Database set-up is wrong. Here's my DB diagram:  http://adelazzam.com/LearningNewestDB.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of large stacktraces, always head to the lastmost one for the real root cause:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Error in allocating a connection. Cause: null

Thus, a connection cannot be obtained from the datasource. Apparently the datasource itself is `null`. You need to create a MySQL datasource in Glassfish. There are several ways:

- By Glassfish admin console: http://www.albeesonline.com/blog/2008/08/06/creating-and-configuring-a-mysql-datasource-in-glassfish-application-server/
- By commandline: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/felipegaucho/archive/2010/03/04/glassfish-v3-resources-administration-cli-tool-asadmin
- By XML config file: http://pooriamellati.wordpress.com/2010/05/21/configure-mysql-pool-and-resource-in-glassfish-v3/

Comment: Thanks so much! One thing though: in the 1st link there, it says: "3. Start your GlassFish Application server by issuing the command ‘asadmin.bat start-domain domain1′ from GLASS_FISH_INSTALL_DIR\bin directory."   <--- confused by "start-domain" part there.

Comment: Let me try another method you posted actually.

Comment: Just enter exactly that command. Or just do whatever handling you usually do to start Glassfish. For example, if you're developing in Eclipse, start it from there. The admin is by default available on http://localhost:4848

Comment: Hi Balus, I got it to work now! Thank you soooo much!  If you ever visit Nawlins, lemme know :)